# Kleisli categories and Eilenberg-Moore categories induced by a pair of subcategories

Tags: category-theory, monads

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a full subcategory of $\mathfrak{B}$, where $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ are both concrete over a given category $\mathfrak{C}$. This means that we can consider the two forgetful functors $U_\mathfrak{B}: \mathfrak{B} \to \mathfrak{C}$ and its corresponding restriction $U_\mathfrak{A}$ to $\mathfrak{A}$.

Assume moreover that the previous forgetful functors are also left adjoint to two functors $G_\mathfrak{B}$ and $G_\mathfrak{A}$, respectively. Hence the adjoint pairs $(U_\mathfrak{A},G_\mathfrak{A})$ and $(U_\mathfrak{B},G_\mathfrak{B})$ induce two (different?) monads $T:=T_\mathfrak{B}$ and $E:=T_\mathfrak{A}$ and, in particular, two (different?) Eilenberg-Moore categories $\mathcal{C}^E$ and $\mathcal{C}^T$ and two (different?) Kleisli categories $(\mathcal{C}_E)$ and $(\mathcal{C}_T)$.

Well my question is the following: is there some well-known relationship between $\mathcal{C}^E$ and $\mathcal{C}^T$ and between $(\mathcal{C}_E)$ and $(\mathcal{C}_T)$?

Comment: Are you sure you want the forgetful functors to be left adjoints? The induced monads then live on $\frak A$ and $\frak B$ respectively. If the forgetful functors are the right adjoints, then both monads live on $\frak C$, so it would be more straightforward to compare them...

Comment: In the situation I'm currently studying, the forgetful functors are left adjoint. However, I need  to compare the corresponding Eilenberg-Moore categories (and the Kleisli ones). It seems quite immediate to see that $C^E$ is a full subcategory of $C^T$ (and similarly $C_E$ is a full subcategory of $C_T$). I'm asking, for instance, if $\mathfrak{A}$ is reflective, then $C^E$ is reflective in $C^T$ (the same for the corresponding Kleisli categories) and all possible analogous questions.